# Sound the bell with sound card present

Tags: c++, c, linux, audio

It is possible From C/C++ in Ubuntu 10.04 Linux to sound the built in bell (buzzer, really) while have a sound card installed?  If so, how?

The goal, of course is to squawk the sounder if something is wrong with the sound card.  In the best of all possible worlds, a backup speaker where my code can "say", "The sound system is broken."

If the buzzer (AST200Q) can eek out more than just a squawk,  how would I have Alsa send sound to it?

Thanks.

Comment: I would use system logging for such purposes (`syslog` in user space, `printk` in kernel modules).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use PC speaker in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447166/how-to-use-pc-speaker-in-linux)

Comment: This is intended to be an alert for a watchman or a service tech without access to the OS.

Comment: @Rob I read the referenced article.  You were correct, this is a dup.  That said, the ioctl sample didn't work.  It gave me one "drip' from my speakers.  Now, if you'll post your comment as an answer, I'll check it as "best answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise an audio/alarm character in ascii... example
`cout << "\a"`
This will make the buzzer normally used in post tests to sound.

Comment: This gives me no bell and no speaker sounds.  Trying something I know to be a no-no, pressing down arrow at a command prompt at the bottom of the history stack, gives me "drips" out of my speakers, but "\a" produces no sound.

Comment: @WesMiller: Try sending it about 1000 times in a loop.

Comment: Well, first put the code in the right place to get it to work.  Then try it many times.  Still didn't work.  I get one "drip" from the speakers.  Wonder if my bell is actually connected.

Comment: The more iterations, the longer the speaker sound. But, Rob's link is what you probably want.

Comment: You may have to put a sleep in between loop iterations as well as flushing the output.

Comment: Pretty sure my bell is not connected or somehow not responding.  I will try the sode suggestions on a different machine.  Thanks to everyone.