# header file for sound() in C in linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to use these functions in C in Linux based system or OS:
    sound()
    nosound()
    dealy()

I can execute it on my Windows OS with dos.h header file but dos.h wont work on Linux based system.

I tried unistd.h, it didnt work. I also tried sound.h, eader file not found error. which header file should I include?

Comment: That's an extremely outdated sound API, which is not supported in Linux as far as I know. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Could you solve it with a modern cross platform audio library such as [libao](http://www.xiph.org/ao/) instead?

Comment: Alternatively, you can search for ways to use the PC speaker in Linux. A simple search gave me this stackoverflow hit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4452936/2971 It seems to use the same kind of mechanisms you are looking for.

Comment: @MagnusHoff i am a beginner in c. can you please explain libao library?

Comment: That question is not very specific, and hard to answer succinctly. It is better if we start by you explaining what you are trying to achieve. You talk about compiling on Android below. Are you making something that will run on Android?

Comment: What kind of program are you writing? Beeping to have user's attention is one thing, synthesizing specific sounds is another.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use this [sndlib library](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/snd/snd/sndlib.html)

> sndlib is a collection of sound file and audio hardware handlers
>   written in C and running currently in various Unices via OSS or ALSA,
>   Mac OSX, and on old Windows systems. It provides relatively
>   straightforward access to many sound file headers and data types, and
>   most of the features of the audio hardware.

Comment: Is there any else header file for this? Because I dont have C compiler on PC and I'm compiling C in my Android phone that doesnt contain all the commands of Linux..

Comment: @user2781245:- I have really no idea about Android phone and its working and how this can be used on it:(

Comment: I tried conio.h but didnt work too.. I need header file that include sound() dealy() and nosound() functions.. :(

Answer (score -1):

Use the `dos.h` header file. It worked for me.

Comment: In a Linux Distro? I doubt it.